# If value in Field1 is null, return value from Field2, otherwise Return String

Tags: sql, ms-access, null, iif

Although this seems simple enough, I cannot get it, nor was I able to find what I needed via searching on here. I need this to be done within the builder, or within my SQL code which is already an extremely lengthy bit of code for what the query is doing already. Here is the basis of the issue:

Fields: `ItemID` | `CustomID`

If there is a value in `CustomID`, I'd like to overwrite the `ItemID` value for that record with a string: `"CK"+CustomID`.

If the `CustomID` field is empty for that record, then keep the original `ItemID`.

I then also need the value for that field to be used to pull the correct data from a linked table. Currently, it will pull the original `ItemID`'s values for subsequent fields, rather than the string `"CK+CustomID"` value that would be substituted in place of `ItemID`.

I thought perhaps an independent subquery would be necessary to discern what the field's value would be, before needing to use that value to gather the subsequent fields from the lookup table.

I am willing to work with the SQL code generated by my query builder, but I am not the greatest with just the code.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing a sample of the content of your table or linked table, nor knowing the names of either of these tables, I would suggest the following example code:

```
select * 
from yourlinkedtable t inner join
(
    select iif(t.customid is null, t.itemid, 'CK' & t.customid) as id
    from yourtable t
) q 
on t.itemid = q.id
```

Here, `yourtable` represents the table containing the `ItemID` and `CustomID` fields, and `yourlinkedtable` represents the table with which your are looking to match the prefixed `ItemID`.

Comment: Hi Lee Mac,

Thanks for the assistance. I was on the right notion, and had it very similar to your proposed solution. After stepping back through it for a bit today, I was able to get what I needed.

I used a subquery and your logic to recreate the table in essence with the corrected ItemID. Then in the main query, I simply referenced that subquery to drive the lookup data I was needing. Works like a charm! Thanks again.

Comment: You're most welcome - I'm pleased to hear that you were able to develop a working solution from my suggestion.